# Filtering List of objects int loop by id from outer loop

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to filter List of objects (comments) sent as attribute using Model class in Spring boot application. I've searched with JS script but my id did not work.

Has anyone any idea if I can compare my **temp** from **files** with my **cmt** from **comments**?
I want to display comments which field from db "**fileID**" equals to **temp.id**

My code:

```
  <table div class="table table-light">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="temp : ${files}">

            <td>
                <div class="container col-sm-8 mt-2">
                    <div class="card card border-dark mb-2">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><span th:text="${temp.title}"/></h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Added by me</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated <span th:text="${temp.data}"/></small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="card-img-top" th:src="${temp.path}" alt="" style="size:auto;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer bg-transparent">
                            <table class="table table-light">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="fileComments">
                                <tr th:each="cmt: ${comments}">
                                    <td>
                                            <span th:text="${cmt.userID}"/>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <span th:text="${cmt.comment}"/>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <span th:text="${cmt.date}"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <form th:action="@{/comment}" th:object="${cmtModel}" style="size:auto" method="post">

                                <input type="hidden" th:value="${temp.id}" name="fileID" />

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{comment}" placeholder=" Add comment"/>
                                <button type="submit" class="button btn-success" style="border-radius: 10px"> Add </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display only the comments that satisfy your condition, add a `th:if` to your `th:each` in the following way:

```
<tr th:each="cmt: ${comments}" th:if="${cmt.fileID} == ${temp.id}">
```

Be careful however, that you will need a getter for fileID and id attributes with standard syntax (might have some trouble with fileID; substitute it for fileId if this is the case, so you have getFileId and getId methods).

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly! I did not thought that it would be possible to filter that like that with thymeleaf.

Comment: @KamilaNowak you're welcome. With thymeleaf you can do pretty much anything when you compose your htmls before sending them to the client (thymeleaf doesn't exist anymore in the client in any way, though).